# Compiling iphone for OS 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, debugging, cocos2d-iphone, release

I'm currently using XCode 3.2.4 and OS 4.2
It's been working smoothly but now I like to make my app work for earlier version 3.1.3 but
these errors keep popping.

```
___restore_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
  +[FontManager sharedManager] in libcocos2d libraries.a(FontManager.o)
  -[ZAttributedString enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:] in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
  +[CDAudioManager alloc] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDAudioManager.o)
  +[CDAudioManager initAsynchronously:channelGroupDefinitions:channelGroupTotal:] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDAudioManager.o)
  +[CDAudioManager sharedManager] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDAudioManager.o)
  -[CDSoundEngine loadBuffersAsynchronously:] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CocosDenshion.o)
  +[SimpleAudioEngine alloc] in libcocos2d libraries.a(SimpleAudioEngine.o)
  +[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] in libcocos2d libraries.a(SimpleAudioEngine.o)
  +[CCTouchDispatcher allocWithZone:] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTouchDispatcher.o)
  +[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTouchDispatcher.o)
```

and

```
___save_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
```

I changed the iOS target to iOS 3.0.
It works for simulator but not the device(above error).

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[ZAttributedString enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:] in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)` shows you that this method call uses a block, which is not supported in iOS 3. Blocks have been introduced only in iOS 4.0.

The Cocos2D website even tells you that you are supposed to use at least iOS SDK 4.1. If you use prior versions, you may be lucky and your code might work if you do not use any technologies introduced later, but there is no guarantee that your app will run.

Comment: so if i'm to release my app to the store. Do I have to speccify it as iOS 4.1 and above?

Comment: You can try to use iOS 4.0 as deployment target. At least blocks will work. I am not quite sure what other functions specifically need 4.1, but the difference between 4.0 and 4.1 is by far smaller than between 3.0 and 4.0. Give it a try. If it compiles for 4.0, you are good to go. If it does not, use 4.1 and you are on the safe side.